# Batch - Using variable inside a variable

Tags: batch-file, variables, cmd, title

**Hello**, today I was playing with **.bat code**.
I would like to change title with changing variable in itself. The way I would like to use title command is from variable `%t%`. I know where is the problem - The variable `%t%` after `set /a n=%n% + 1` is outdated and still have value `n=0`. Is there any way to automatically update `%t%` without typing again `set t=title changing %n%`? I Thought there will be some way to "lock" the variable `%n%` so it get the last possible value. (after typing itself in the `%t%`)

```
set /a n=0
set t=title changing %n%
%t%
pause
set /a n=%n% + 1
%t%
pause
```

*sorry for not good EN,*
**THX for any response <3**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /a n=0
set "t=title changing ^!n^!"
%t%
pause
set /a n=%n% + 1
%t%
pause
```

For an explanation, look for "Delayed Expansion" in this site...

PS - You may enter `set /a n=%n% + 1` in this way: `set /a n=n + 1` or even in this simpler one: `set /a n += 1`

Comment: Thx, that was what i wanted to know :)